# How to encrypt the AuthProvider consumerSecret via the metadata api?

Tags: metadata-api, platform-encryption

[AuthProvider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_authproviders.htm) specifies that when creating an auth provider you need to encrypt the consumerSecret.

It then specifies that this can be done via a *manual* process using an outbound change set.

> When using `create()` this field must be encrypted. To create an encrypted form of the consumer secret from plain text:
>   1. Create an auth provider with the consumerSecret plain text value.
>   2. Save the auth provider.
>   3. Create an outbound change set that includes the auth provider component.
>   The new change set .xml file will have an entry in the form ++XYZ++ where ++XYZ++ is the encrypted secret.

Is there any way to do this *programmatically* instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is currently possible using the Metadata API directly.

As you found, if you try deploy an `.authprovider` file with a plain text value in for the `consumerSecret` you get the error:

> Consumer Secret must be specified in encrypted form.

The problem is that the Metadata API works with the encrypted values.

Imagine for a moment Salesforce did give you the ability to encrypt the value yourself. They would have also inadvertently given you the ability to decyrpt it .

---

As a work around, you could switch to the Partner API or REST API version of [AuthProvider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authprovider.htm). This version exposes the plain text version of the consumerSecret

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned, it can't be done via the Metadata API. However, I was able to confirm that you are able to create an AuthProvider via the REST API. Below is an example of creating a Salesforce AuthProvider to verify the behaviour (assuming you've got an access token).

```bash
curl <INSERT_SALESFORCE_URL>/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/AuthProvider/ -H "Authorization: Bearer <INSERT_ACCESS_TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @authprovider.json -X POST
```

**authprovider.json example file**

```json
{
    "AuthorizeUrl": "INSERT_SALESFORCE_URL/services/oauth2/authorize",
    "ConsumerKey": "INSERT_CONSUMER_KEY",
    "ConsumerSecret": "INSERT_CONSUMER_SECRET",
    "DeveloperName": "AuthProviderName",
    "FriendlyName": "AuthProviderName",
    "OptionsIncludeOrgIdInId": "true",
    "ProviderType": "Salesforce",
    "TokenUrl": "INSERT_SALESFORCE_URL/services/oauth2/token"
}
```